# Magento how to incorporate product attribute set into URL for XML sitemap and canonical URL

Tags: seo, magento-1.7

By default the Magento XML sitemap and canonical URL features ignore categories and write all URLS as

```
www.example.com/model1a
```

It appears that these features can't use categories because a product can be under more than one category. However, a product can only be under one attribute set, and it just so happens that my attribute sets line up pretty well with my base level categories so I was wondering what changes I would need to make to get Magento to use attribute sets in the XML sitemap and canonical URL tags? For example, if product "Model1A" was of attribute set "Foo", I would like the XML sitemap and canonical URL to show:

```
www.example.com/foo/model1a
```

I've been looking around for a bit but could not find a straight forward explanation about this. I suppose for the canonical URLs I could disable the feature and edit a phtml template to include the tag manually the way I want to build it, but I'm particularly lost when it comes to changing how the XML sitemap is generated. Any suggestions?

Comment: How is it even possible that you replied that fast? =p  Thanks I'll take a look at this link!

Comment: Cut & paste helps. ;)

Comment: Well no luck here I wonder if I could get this post moved to the magento SE site?

Comment: Flag it and the mods will do that for you

Comment: I don't think this can be done easily, but can you give more details about why do you want this? The product URL is unique anyway. What's the problem if you generate the sitemap with mysite.com/product ?

Comment: Because I want the URLs in the sitemap to match the canonical URL tag and I would prefer them both to be more descriptive than just mysite.com/product. I have different categories of products and I believe there is an SEO benefit to being descriptive with the URLs but even if there is not I still think it looks cleaner/more professional.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your Magento product URL and attribute set by two ways.

1. Either you can handle product save event and modify the URL
2. You can go to Catalog->URL Rewrite and change the specific URLS. This may not be suitable for your case.

Comment: can you give an example for observer which modifies the product url after save event?